# How to copy files onto a raspberry pi os using only the microSD it is on - no networking, bluetooth or usb?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, filesystem, file-sharing

I would like to copy a file to a raspberry pi using a Macbook.
I have installed ubuntu on the 64GB microsd and booted it up no problem.

I have turned off bluetooth and wifi/networking on the raspberry pi.
I do not have a USB drive.

When I put the microSD card into my mac - I only see a `system-boot` drive. Apparently the files and directories on ubuntu are in a filesystem unwriteable or even readable by a standard mac.
I tried copying the file to the `system-boot` drive but when I check on ubuntu - I can't find `system-boot` anywhere.

So how can I copy this file onto the microSD?

Comment: There are at least two partitions on a Pi SD card -- the first is a small vfat fs required by the SoC, it looks for firmware and a bootloader there. This is what you can see now. The second partition is the OS root filesystem.  I'm not familiar with the Ubuntu Pi distro -- which, no offense intended, seems a poor choice if you are not already familiar with the basics I'm regurgitating here, ie., you are obviously new to linux and would be better  off sticking to the distro with the most support (Raspbian/RpiOS) -- but setting that warning aside, the linux root filesystem is `ext4` formatted...

Comment: ...my understanding as a non-Mac user is that Macs do have decent support for ext4, but you may have to click some buttons to make it work (**clue being `ext4` filesystem**).  Hopefully someone more Mac-y will come along soon ;)  All this said, **the first partition is accessible from the running system**, so you could just copy it to what you see then look in `/boot` for it on a running Pi.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac never had native support for ext4, although there used to be user space drivers. Changes to SIP have effectively prevented these from working.

There are third party (paid) drivers but like most keep changing (and thus you have to keep paying).

You can access the FAT partition, but I agree with goldilocks comments.

Frankly your best option is to use networking. I use Samba, ftp, ssh or nfs to exchange files.